# Intuitive understanding of frequency

Tags: frequency, math

I know that $f = \frac{\text{cycles}}{\text{unit of time}}$  and I know that period $T = \text{time it takes to complete one cycle}$.

So if we take the definition

$f = \frac{1}{T} = \frac{\text{1 cycle}}{\text{time it takes to complete one cycle}}$

So if we have some $x$ cycles we get that $f = \frac{x \text{ cycles}}{\text{time it takes to complete one cycle}}$.

How can we have $x > 1$ if it takes $T$ to complete a cycle? In other words, how could $x > 1$ have completed in the time it takes to complete one cycle?

I’m guessing that $T$ is somehow decoupled from $x$ and I’ve got my definitions mixed up.

Comment: In your second equation for $f$, the $1$ has no units. So, $f$ has units $[\text{cycle}/\text{s}]$ (cycles per second) and $T$ has units $[\text{s}/\text{cycle}]$ (seconds per cycle). Also, note that it is very common not to use cycles as a unit and define Hz as $1/s$ (or $s^{-1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about **units and dimensions**. And I'm probably not *the* guy to cast an answer on that but I would like to state it as follows. In short; length, time, mass etc. are *dimensions*, whereas meter, seconds, kg are *units* of them respectively in SI. (for other dimensions and units, a physics book might help.)

Now, if a wheel rotates 7 times in 2 seconds; it's rotation frequency $f$ is found as:
$$ f = \frac{7 ~\text{ cycles}}{2 ~\text{ seconds}} = 3.5 ~\text{cycles-per-second (cps)}.$$

As can be seen, frequency is given by a (cycle) **number** divided by **time**. The cycle *number* has no physical units or dimensions; it's just a repetition count. Whereas the duration *time* has a unit of seconds (in SI).

Thus the dimesion of frequency is **1/time**, whose SI unit is $1/s = s^{-1}$. This unit is also, and more frequently, denoted as **Hz** where it (implicitly) stands for *(cycles) per second* indeed. So, $3.5$ Hz stands for $3.5$ cycles per second.

Now, similarly the **period** is defined as the **duration time per one cycle**. Again note that since *cycle* is a number and does not posses a unit, then the dimension of the period is **time** and its **unit is seconds** in SI. But you can always denote it also as *seconds per cycle*, rarely practiced though.

Finally, using both notations you have 
$$ T = \frac{1}{f} $$

So if frequency $f$ is defined with a unit of Hz ($s^{-1}$), then the period will have a unit of seconds (s) in SI. Otherwise if you define frequency as *cycles per second* then the period unit will be *seconds per cycle*.

So if you define the frequency as $3.5$ cycles-per-second , then the period associated is:
$$T = \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{ 3.5 \frac{\text{cyc}}{s} } = \frac{2}{7} \frac{\text{s}}{\text{cyc}}$$

Otherwise, in accepted norm, as was you would define freqquency as $3.5$ Hz. its period in SI will be:
$$ \boxed{ T = \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{ 3.5 s^{-1} } = \frac{2}{7} ~\text{ s} } $$